# Is substitution of symbolic expressions for JordanDecomposition correct?

Tags: matrix, symbolic

Is it correct if I substitute letters A-Z for 25 expressions that are in a 5x5 matrix, run JordanDecomposition and then substitute expressions back?

The process makes no progress after a day with original symbolic expressions, but I don't want to do something incorrect.

Comment: The following works, but you get a large expression: m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {5, 5}]
JordanDecomposition[m]

Comment: I believe a sufficient condition for this to be correct is that the eigenvalues of the original matrix are distinct (no multiplicity, that is). I will remark that this is really a math question and not related to Mathematica per se.